# How to use header exchange to send and recieve java objects as messages from queues in rabbitmq

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am trying to use header exchange in rabbitmq to produce and consume messages. When i am trying to produce the message i have to convert the message to byte[] but on the consumer side i'm not able to deserialize it properly. I had used classMapper in my jackson dependency but still it is not able to decode the class. I am not sure if i'm missing something or if i'm doing it wrong.

ProducerConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig 
{

    @Value("${exchangeName}")
    String exchange;

    @Value("${queueName}")
    String queueName;

    @Value("${queueName1}")
    String queueName1;

    @Bean
    public List<Object> topicBindings() 
    {

        Queue headerQueue = new Queue(queueName);
        Queue headerQueue1 = new Queue(queueName1);

        Map<String,Object> mapForQueue = new HashMap<>();
        mapForQueue.put("key", "value");
        mapForQueue.put("key2", "value2");

        Map<String,Object> mapForQueue1 = new HashMap<>();
        mapForQueue.put("key", "value");
        mapForQueue1.put("key1", "value1");

        HeadersExchange headerExchange = new HeadersExchange(exchange);

        return Arrays.asList
                (
                        headerQueue,headerQueue1,headerExchange,
                        BindingBuilder.bind(headerQueue).to(headerExchange).whereAny(mapForQueue),
                        BindingBuilder.bind(headerQueue1).to(headerExchange).whereAll(mapForQueue1)
                );
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() 
    {
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        jsonConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper());
        return jsonConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultClassMapper classMapper() 
    {
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping = new HashMap<>();
        idClassMapping.put("String", String.class);
        idClassMapping.put("Employee", Employee.class);
        classMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);
        return classMapper;
    }

}
```

SenderClass

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQSender 
{
    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    @Value("${exchangeName}")
    private String exchange;

    public void send(Employee employee) 
    { 
        Message message = MessageBuilder.withBody(SerializationUtils.serialize(employee))
                .setHeader("key", "value")
                .setHeader("key1", "value1")
                .build();

        amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange,"",message);
    }

}
```

ConsumerConfiguration Class

```
@EnableRabbit
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() 
    {
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        jsonConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper());
        return jsonConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultClassMapper classMapper() 
    {
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping = new HashMap<>();
        idClassMapping.put("String", String.class);
        idClassMapping.put("Employee", Employee.class);
        classMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);
        return classMapper;
    }

}
```

ConsumerApplication

```
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{'${combinedQueue}'.split(';')}")
public class RabbitMqListener 
{
    @RabbitHandler
    public void recievedMessage(@Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String rk,@Payload Employee employee) 
    {
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Header recieved  = "+rk);
        System.out.println("Recieved Object Message From Important Queue " + employee);
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************************");
    }

    @RabbitHandler
    public void recievedMessage1(@Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String rk,@Payload byte[] object) 
    {
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("Header recieved  = "+rk);

        Employee emp = (Employee)SerializationUtils.deserialize(object);

        System.out.println("Recieved String Message From Important Queue " + emp);
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************************");
    }

}
```

Employee class

```
public class Employee
{

    private String empName;
    private String empId;

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empName=" + empName + ", empId=" + empId + "]";
    }

}
```

ErrorLog

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.rabbitmq.consumer.service.RabbitMqListener.recievedMessage1(java.lang.String,byte[])' threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:198) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1552) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1478) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not deserialize object type
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:98) ~[spring-amqp-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:75) ~[spring-amqp-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.rabbitmq.consumer.service.RabbitMqListener.recievedMessage1(RabbitMqListener.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.DelegatingInvocableHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocableHandler.java:130) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:60) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:190) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.poc.springbootrabbitmq.model.Employee
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:686) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:92) ~[spring-amqp-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted

2019-05-06 00:39:35.801  WARN 2780 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.s.c.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter   : Could not convert incoming message with content-type [application/octet-stream], 'json' keyword missing.
```

Also, can i produce the message in any format other than byte[] ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2019-05-06 00:39:35.801  WARN 2780 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.s.c.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter   : Could not convert incoming message with content-type [application/octet-stream], 'json' keyword missing.

The Jackson converter will only convert if the `content_type` property contains `json` (e.g. `application/json`).

Comment: I am trying to send the message in JSON format using Jackson dependency but Since i am using messagebuilder i'm forced to use byte[]. Is there any way i can send the message in other format in header exchange

Comment: Also, the stack trace says that the message format is unknown whereas i have used classMapper in my configurations. Kindly suggest me what may be i'm doing wrong...

Comment: Oh; that won't work (`convertAndSend` with `Message`). Why are you doing that? Simply use `convertAndSend(employee)`. If you want to add headers, use the overloaded method that takes a `MessagePostProcessor`.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, can i produce the message in any format other than byte[] ???

- Yes, it is possible.

Jackson (generally) is used to convert a Java object into a Json string (i.e. character data). You appear to be trying to do this but you are also trying to send the class as binary data (byte[]). You need to choose one.

The stacktrace is trying to help:

- **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.poc.springbootrabbitmq.model.Employee.** The class you are trying to serialise is not being found so even
  though it has a message it doesn't know what to do with it.
- **o.s.a.s.c.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter   : Could not convert incoming message with content-type [application/octet-stream], 'json' keyword missing.** This is telling you, that you are sending binary content (and Jackson is confused, because it is expecting Json i.e. character data).

Perhaps this is closer to what you are trying to achieve? https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2016/10/23/produce-and-consume-json-messages-with-spring-boot-amqp/

Comment: I don't want to send message in byte[] but since i'm using messagebuilder i have to use byte[]. Can you suggest me some way so that i can send the message in other formats and also include header in the message. Kindly Notice that i strictly want to use header exchange.